# Updating DataGridView after delete something in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I am trying to delete some rows from `DataGridView` selecting a couple of them, but I cannot do it. I will explain it with the code.

```
if ((bool)dtrow.Cells[0].Value == true)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();

    int RowsAffected = 0;
    string queryDelete = "DELETE FROM InfoFile WHERE FileName='" + dtrow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(queryDelete);
    cmd.Connection = con;

    RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (RowsAffected > 0)
    {
        test();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Records not found!", "Try again", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The `teste();` method will update the `DataGridView` after delete something.

```
public void test()
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT SelectedOrNot, Status, FileName, FileType, FileSize, FilePath,
                                                Created, Modified, Access, PCName FROM InfoFile", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT SelectedOrNot, Status, NomeFicheiro, TipoFicheiro, TamanhoFicheiro, CaminhoFicheiro,
                                                Criado, Modificado, Acedido, NomePC FROM InfoFicheiro", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = false;
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = row[1];
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = row[2].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = row[3].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = row[4].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = row[5].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = row[6].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = row[7].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = row[8].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = row[9].ToString();

                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < 0)
                {
                    int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0];
                }
                else if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0];
                }

                foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    drow.Height = 18;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

If I comment the `test();` method it will remove the selected rows. If I use the `teste();` method it will remove just one row but it will update.

So do you have any idea I could I solve it?

Comment: Sin you have a datatable why not fill with datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Because it will delete but does not refresh the `DataGridView` @jdweng

Comment: You can update by simply setting DataSource to null and then back to DataTable.

Comment: I've updated the post see the `teste();` method @jdweng

Comment: If you make changes to the DataTable you need to use method dt.AcceptChanges();  Then set datagridview1.DataSource to null.  You do not need to manually load DGV by code.

Comment: Can you post it, because I am not getting it? @jdweng

Comment: dt.AcceptChanges();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I think I know this is not updating well. This `DataGridView` already have columns added and if I use this method it will duplicate the columns in the `DataGridView` @jdweng

Comment: Why manually add columns?

Comment: But that is not the problem because I got the same method after inserting data and it will update the `DataGridView` without any problema. If I run breakpoint into the  if (RowsAffected > 0){ test(); } it will update but remove only one. If I comment the teste(); it will delete what I've selected(more than one) but does not update the `DataGridView` of course. @jdweng

Comment: Add an update button to the form which the operate will press so you don't do the work multiple times.  The operator know when he is finished, the code doesn't.

Comment: It works. I would like my application to be user friendly and clicking on a button it's a lost of time @jdweng